# In what way are geometric realization and taking projective resolutions the same?

Tags: category-theory

I've heard it stated that geometric realization of a simplicial set is analogous to projective resolutions of a module.

How precise can this be made? Is there some general notion of geometric realization that recovers both geometric realization of a simplicial set and the projective resolution of a module?

Comment: I don't agree. The topological analogue of finding a projective resolution of a module is finding a CW complex structure on a space (or a space homotopy equivalent to it), or if you prefer, finding a simplicial set whose geometric realization is homotopy equivalent to it. Note that geometric realization is a functor but finding projective resolutions isn't. It's useful here to know about the Dold-Kan correspondence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dold%E2%80%93Kan_correspondence

Comment: In what sense is taking projective resolutions not functorial? Don't the usual model structures on chain complexes have functorial fibrant/cofibrant replacements?